# How to determine a good simulation time?

Tags: simulation, networks

So I'm doing network simulations, and I'd like to know how long does each simulation run needs to be.
My network is quite simple: its composed of **multiple** M/M/1/H queues (Markovian processes + finite waiting queues):

- clients arrive at some node(s), are put into waiting queues
- each node process one client at a time
- a processed client is sent to another node, or goes out of the system
- all random processes follow a Poisson distribution

The finite waiting queues prevents it of being a Poisson process: the output of a node is no longer Poisson, so neither will be the inputs of the nodes after it.

I thought I could try to plot the variance and mean of the waiting time (inside the queues) and see when it becomes "stable"?
Would that be a good solution? How else could I do that?

Comment: If you start with an empty queue and no-one being served, you don't need to wait for it to become stable; the system renews every time the queue becomes empty and no-one is being served, so the long run is just an endless repetition of short runs that begin in the "empty" state.  The wonders of the Poisson distribution at work.

Comment: Yes, but as the waiting queues are finite (some clients get ejected), and there are many of them linked to each other, the overall process is not poisson.

Comment: (I edited the question to reflect your post remark @jbowman )

Comment: Yes, but when the entire system is empty, you're still at a renewal.  Since you have finite queue lengths, your mean time between renewals is finite regardless of considerations of traffic intensity, etc.  The Poisson arrival part means that when everything is empty, the time since it became empty is irrelevant to the future evolution of the system, so all that counts for the renewal is that the system be empty (otherwise, the time since the system became empty would be relevant too, making life more difficult.)